# Store images in SDL Tridion to be used for different Components

Tags: 2011

I have a Component with some HTML and that contains some images, these images are linked to an external site, after publishing the Page I can see the images working, but once our SDL Tridion published site is up and running, we will disconnect the external site and then the images will stop working.

I have already downloaded these images to my local file system and I want to upload them into the SDL Tridion CMS, and later I will update my Components with the image urls from the SDL Tridion cms.

What is the best location to store these images? I have a folder "News" that contains multiple news Components, I am thinking to create an "images" folder under the "News" folder, is that how images and links are handled in SDL Tridion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed you can store Images in tridion as multimedia components, it depends on your Blueprint and your application requirements but as a good practice you should store images in a high level folder called for instance `images`, by default Tridion will publish all your images to the Multimedia Path that is specified in your Web site publication (by default it is /Images). When you reference a multimedia component in a component you will see something like this.

```
<img src="tcm:1-123" title="My Image" />
```

If you are using DWT and this reference is in a RTF Tridion will manage it automatically. However if you don't use it you will need to specify some tridion sintax in your template and to have something like this.

```
<img xlink:href="tcm:1-123" tridion:targetattribute="src" tridion:type="Multimedia" title="My Image" />
```

Then you will need to include the Publish Binaries In Package and Link Resolver TBBs and it will be converted to.

```
<img src="/Images/myimage.jpg" title="My Image" />
```

Answer (score 5):

First and foremost, you should probably never want to use direct image links in your SDL Tridion published content, since as you mention, then your content has a dependency on an external server.

Images and other binary content (like downloadable files, e.g. PDF and Word documents) is supposed to be stored in a Multimedia Component in SDL Tridion. Then you can directly make a (Multimedia) Component link to that from your content Component(s).

Then to answer your next question, where to store these Multimedia Components. It doesn't really matter where you store them, as the relation from your content to the Multimedia Component is a managed link. So if you decide to place the images (Multimedia Components) in for example Folder A, and later you move them to Folder B, the images references will automatically be updated (actually the image reference inside SDL Tridion is not updated, since that doesn't contain the path, but just to make it clear, you don't have to worry about them).

When choosing the best place to store these images in your CMS, you only have to consider the Authors and Editors who need to use/find them. If these images are only used for News Articles, then a Images folder under the News folder would be a good place.

However when these images could also be relevant for other Articles or content, then I would suggest to create a Images folder right under the root (Building Blocks) folder, so that every Author and Editor know where all images are stored. It will be beneficial to create a sub folder structure under that Images folder to categorize types of images when you have a lot of them. But as mentioned, you can always move the images at a later stage to another folder without having to worry about the references in the content.

Answer (score 1):

Great answers from Bart and Eric, but want to clarify some points to make it clearer on how SDL Tridion handles images.

Regarding the following and to be sure, **there are no "image urls" in Tridion**. Unless you change how images are published (in templating code) the folders and structure groups are independent of where content (in Tridion folders) is stored.

> I have already downloaded these images to my local file system and I
>   want to upload them into the SDL Tridion CMS, and later I will update
>   my Components with the image urls from the SDL Tridion cms.

In addition to not making direct image links to other systems, you should not make direct image links in Tridion based on path. **Use the component link button** in rich text format areas or select multimedia components in fields.

Having an image in a News folder (e.g. News/Image.png) does not represent paths in the presentation server (website). And even if you add code to place images in a certain folder, you still don't need to manually make image urls.

> What is the best location to store these images? I have a folder
>   "News" that contains multiple news Components, I am thinking to create
>   an "images" folder under the "News" folder, is that how images and
>   links are handled in SDL Tridion?

I agree with the other answers that location doesn't impact where you publish multimedia to, but consider two more points:

- Permission settings automatically apply to sub-folders. Keeping content grouped together based on how they're managed will simplify permissions.
- Consider setting a default multimedia schema to your image folder. This will simplify authoring them.